# Error: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webclient

I am trying to upload a file on a web server. Here is my code

```
private void Submit1_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((File1.PostedFile != null) && (File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0))
        {
            string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
            string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fn;

           // byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(SaveLocation);
            try
            {
                Uri webAddress = new Uri("http://www.mysiteurl.com/testupload.php");

                wcUploader.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wcUploader_UploadProgressChanged);
                wcUploader.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(wcUploader_UploadFileCompleted);
                wcUploader.UploadFileAsync(webAddress,"PUT",fn);
                //Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
                //Note: Exception.Message returns a detailed message that describes the current exception. 
                //For security reasons, we do not recommend that you return Exception.Message to end users in 
                //production environments. It would be better to return a generic error message. 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
        }
    }

    void wcUploader_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
    }

    void wcUploader_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = (string)e.UserState + "\n\n"
                                 + "Uploaded " + e.BytesSent + "/" + e.TotalBytesToSend
                                 + "b (" + e.ProgressPercentage + "%)";
    }
```

Here **wcUploader** is object of **WebClient** class.

When I execute this code I am getting this error

> Error: An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

Basically I am trying to upload a file on a web server. While uploading I want to show the progress of uploading. So, How can I solve this error ? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You can forget about showing the progress this way, only works in WinForms/WPF. You'll need Ajax.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for reply. How can I do by using Ajax? Is there any example? Basically I am developing windows phone app there is one feature so, that's why I want to upload a file to server. Is there any example to upload a file to server?

Comment: Not my expertise. But do update your tags, helps to attract the right people.